# Can this summation be converted to an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

Lately I have been playing around and thinking about this function

$$f\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=2}^{1000}\left(\max\left(1,\operatorname{floor}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\right)-\max\left(1,\operatorname{floor}\left(\frac{x-1}{n}\right)\right)\right)$$

I am trying to somehow simplify it with some algebraic manipulations or convert it to an integral, but because of how discrete it is, I haven't made any progress. Does anyone know how to do anything with this function? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $\text{floor}(x/n) = \text{floor}((x-1)/n)$ unless $nk+1 > x \ge nk$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: Though this function is certainly [interesting](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tmdeklvn8u) , your post as currently stated is vague and has no context. Voting to close.